# Parse Element ID within iframe using Webview in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, iframe, webview2

I have a webpage that loads caller data when a caller calls. I am trying to parse the element ids but they are loaded in an iframe. How would i go about doint this?

The iframe is and the elements are on default.html `<iframe onload="UserFrameLoaded();" name="cmUserFrame" id="view_cmUserFrame" style="display: block; overflow: scroll;" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="1415px" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" src="./CallManager_files/default.html"></iframe>`

the code im using is

```
Dim firstNameText As String = Await WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('m.first_name').textContent")
```

i tried

```
Dim firstNameText As String = Await WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('view_cmUserFrame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('m.first_name').textContent")
```

Im not sure if the iframes source is on another domain. Im hoping not...
I can probably just save the webpage locally and then load default.html directly but i am not sure how to save the webpage with webview either.

Comment: adding 2 files kinda defeats the purpose of trying to use JS from the top level document. From what I can see  your second JS code should work. Open dev tools go to the console and test your JS to see if you get a cross domain error.

Comment: You do not have nested frames so I see no issue in getting that from from Webview2 with the framecreated event.

Comment: document.getElementById('m.first_name')
null
document.getElementById('view_cmUserFrame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('m.first_name')
VM1682:1 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at <anonymous>:1:58

Comment: I tried framecreated event but it doesnt get triggered. Unless im calling it wrong? I think maybe its not possible due to cross domain

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: I am testing with this 

Dim IframeList As New List(Of CoreWebView2Frame)

 Private Sub FrameCreated(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2FrameCreatedEventArgs)
        IframeList.Add(e.Frame)
        MsgBox(IframeList(0).ToString)

    End Sub

Comment: You will have to edit your question a put the code there properly. I suggest you show how you initialize the webview2 AND where you add the event handler for the frame created.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much are asking a Javascript question, however, things might be easier for you if you understand a little more about Webview2 and how you can access those frames.

First option is [FrameCreated Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.framecreated?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1343.22) which will fire when the cmUserFrame is created in the top document. From this you get a frame and you can then use [ExecuteScriptAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2frame.executescriptasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1343.22#microsoft-web-webview2-core-corewebview2frame-executescriptasync(system-string)) from that frame object.

Next up you have [AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.addscripttoexecuteondocumentcreatedasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1343.22) with this it will inject your script into each document that is created. In this case you could have Javascript that checks the name of the document/Frame and then if it is the right frame continues with your javascript.

With respect to you actual Javascript, without knowing the actual page it is difficult to know. open the Dev tools of either Chrome or edge and then the console and copy past your javascript into there to see if it works there first. If it works there then you have a timing issue. If it does not work then you need to work on what is not being found.

**Updated From Comments**
To help you understand the Webview2 frame events here is an Issue from Github
One [more link from Webview2 GitHub issues.](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwivoJSd39P6AhXOuaQKHfAeAwYQFnoECBwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FMicrosoftEdge%2FWebView2Feedback%2Fissues%2F670&usg=AOvVaw3XTOwNOz7Pvxs2N6RJNqoG)

Specifically to answer your questions.

1. Implement FrameCreated
2. Wait for the frame with the name you want
3. Wait for DomContentCompleted event
4. Call ExecuteScriptAsync ONE THE FRAME you get from 2

**Code would then be assuming that that frame's document is as you have in your js**

```
Dim firstNameText As String = Await WebView21FRAME.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('m.first_name').textContent")
```

Comment: Thank you. I have done this. I'm pretty sure the source of the frame is from another domain and that is why it's not working

Comment: Then use the webview2 events to get your js injected in.

Comment: But i can not access the iframe. How can i do that unless i can access it?

From what i have read, this is not possible if the iframe source is on another domain.
Even with js

Comment: Also the FrameCreated Event is only for top level frames.

Comment: I think you might need take a step back a think about what you are doing. If you are calling this document.getElementById('view_cmUserFrame') then this is going to find an element within the top level document.  Assuming you know your Javascript then this frame would be shown in the WebView2 events.

Comment: https://reactgo.com/get-element-from-iframe-javascript/

"Note: If you want to access an iframe, it should be on the same domain otherewise you can’t access it because of security reasons (like XSS)."

It not a matter of taking a step back or how much i do or don't know. Its not possible due to cross site scripting attack vectors.

Comment: Sorry for trying to help. I’ve updated my answer with an issue from GitHub. READ it to the end as someone from Microsoft gives the guy the same answer I am.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I'm sorry if it sounded as if I didn't. In order for this to work, I would need the admin of the domain hosting the data to authorize my domain. And that is not possible.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/ucwa/cross_domainiframe

Comment: The link you sent also says that you can not access elements from cross domain iframes. The last post that talks about jave injection does not refer to cross domain. He was just showing there is now support for iframe scripts.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer that is how you will access the frame.

Comment: Thanks. I cant get it to work. NULL. Thanks for your help. I have moved on from this project.

Comment: FrameCreated Does not fire when any iframe is created.

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2440
FrameCreated is not called for iframe inside another iframe #2440

Its not possible

Comment: What website are you doing this with? You don’t have nested iFrame, if you do than your original JavaScript had no chance of working.

Comment: Thats what i thought. Its Cisco CallManager. I was trying to pull the information like the zip code and then automatically input the state and other options like this. That is why i cant post the HTML as it has sensitive information... Im now trying to figure out how to use webview to automatically save the webpage and elements locally where i can pull the data. When i save the page, i can just open the iframe html file and get the elements easily with the method i mentioned..

Comment: Its called in after with js..

<script type="text/javascript" src="./CallManager_files/callmgr.js.download"></script>

Comment: is there a test version? Otherwise open it in Chrome to the page you want to get the info from either have a dummy person available or change the values, take a screen shot AND open up DEV tools > go to Elements > right click on the top HTML element > copy element which should copy the whole html, past in text file and upload both to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have updated my question and provided the html and the screenshots that you requested. Thanks for helping me with this. It would really help me if i can get this to work.